# Read or write Entity Managers in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony

I am using Symfony2 for my application which has read and write databases.

I have already define different connections and Entity managers in my config file. It is working fine when I create Entity object in controller and Repositories like that

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager('write');
```

Now the problem is I have also create some services and in service argument I have given Entity manager like that

```
services:
    app.counterservices:
        id: app.counterservices
        class: AppBundle\Services\CounterService
        arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
```

How can I define in service that which Entity manager I want to user Read or Write?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your service configuration, choose the entity manager you want like this

```
services:
    app.counterservices:
        id: app.counterservices
        class: AppBundle\Services\CounterService
        arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.write_entity_manager"]
```

or

```
services:
    app.counterservices:
        id: app.counterservices
        class: AppBundle\Services\CounterService
        arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.read_entity_manager"]
```

Comment: Thank you Carlos Granados for your suggestion but i want more as i have constructor in my service class where I gave \Doctrine $doc then $doc->getEntityManager('write'); it gives me error

Comment: Sorry, my answer was not correct, I have edited it with the right answer